# How to make sure all fields are filled in php?

Tags: php, validation, security

Hi.
I am trying to write some php to export input to csv format. It works really well, except it doesn't check to make sure all fields are filled. How can I make sure they are all filled.

```
<?php
$txt = "report.csv";
$fh = fopen($txt, 'a+');
if (isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['lastname']) && isset($_POST['version']) && isset($_POST['description'])) { // check if both fields are set
   $first = $_POST['firstname'];
   $last =  $_POST['lastname'];
   $version = $_POST['version'];
   $description = $_POST['description'];
   $q = "\"";
   $c = ",";
   $check=$first.$last.$version.$descrption;
   $txt=$q.$first.$q.$c.$q.$last.$q.$c.$q.$version.$q.$c.$q.$description.$q;
   if (strpos($check, '"') !== false){
   echo file_get_contents("/quotes.html");
   } else {
   file_put_contents('report.csv',$txt."\n",FILE_APPEND); // log to data.txt
   echo file_get_contents("yay.html");
   exit();
   }
} else {
echo file_get_contents("notfilled.html");
}

?>
```

HTML

```
  <form action="problem.php" method="POST">
    <label for="fname"><h3>First Name</h3></label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname">

    <label for="lname"><h3>Last Name</h3></label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname">
    <label for="version"><h3>Version</h3></label>
    <select id="version" name="version">
      <option value="0.1">0.1</option>
      <option value="0.2">0.2</option>
      <option value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>
    <label for="description"><h3>Description</h3></br><p1>Please describe your problem with details. Explain what the problem is how to reproduce it.</label>
    <textarea id="description" name="description" style="height:100px"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

Comment: `!empty($_POST['firstname'])` if you just want to check for empty case.

Comment: Replace `isset` with `empty`. Also it's a good practice to apply `trim` before checking.

Comment: `empty` or `!empty`

Comment: `!empty` worked thanks! Whats the difference from `!empty` and `isset`

Comment: You could always add `required` to your HTML fields (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp).

Comment: @Nigel Ren Yes, but someone could inspect element and change the HTML.

Comment: @u_mulder How would I use `trim`?

Comment: What if they put `"sometext,","something else"\n` in a field.  Would this cause problems with the way you store the data in the file?

Comment: @Nigel Ren Quotes are not allowed with this line `if (strpos($check, '"') !== false){`

Comment: But `\n` is allowed?

Comment: @Nigel Ren I am not seeing the problem. I entered `\n` into one of the fields and it displayed it fine in the cvs file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `!empty` to check the values are empty or not.
if you want to check for other case too such as name should not be number the you should use `regex` too.

`if (!empty($_POST['firstname']) && !empty($_POST['lastname']) && !empty($_POST['version']) && !empty($_POST['description'])) {`

For you comment `Whats the difference from !empty and isset`?

Suppose you have a variable

```
$test= "";

if(empty($test)) // it return true because "" is empty

if(isset($test)) // return true because $test is defined
```

***while***

```
if(empty($anotherTest)) // return true because its null

if(isset($anotherTest)) // return false because is not defined
```

Comment: @Josh : I also explain you the difference b/w `empty` and `isset`.